# SwiftUI onChange for the horiz/vert size classes?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build an ios app (in ios 14) that reacts to changes in the current size classes. Specifically, I have a data model that I want to set different values on based on the size classes of the view. I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to do this.

To be clear - I don't want to change something in the *view* based on size class. I want to change something in the data model, which, in my humble opinion, should not be "aware" of the view.

I'm trying to set an `onChange` handler in my root view in SwiftUI, but can't come up with the proper incantation such that a change in either of the size classes (horiz/vert) cause my `onChange` handler to fire.

In other words, I'm trying to run arbitrary code when the size class changes.

If that makes sense to any of the far-more-talented ios developers on SO, please let me know. If there is any more information I can provide, please ask.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Would you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GeometryReader to update the last ui width/height to the view model. By placing an inline if statement inside the view the "vm.render" method will be called on every GeometryReader dimension change. Also, unlike .onAppear() this if statement is called on orientation changes.

It seemed far less complex to use GeometryReader with an inline if statement than to hook up orientation events using:
UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications(), plus subscribe, plus an .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher...

I'm fairly certain this technique is not causing unsafe content rendering since it is blocking all child content until the method is evaluated. If anyone knows of an issue setting variables in an external class in the middle of view render let me know. This does seem eerily easy to do with no down sides so far.

```
import SwiftUI

fileprivate class viewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var _uiLastSize:CGSize = CGSize(width:0, height:0)
    
    public func render(_ size:CGSize) -> Bool {
        guard size != CGSize.zero else {
            return false
        }

        if size != _uiLastSize {
            print("resize")
            _uiLastSize = size
        }

        return true
    }
}

struct TesterView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var vm:viewModel
    init() {
        vm = viewModel()
    }
            
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            if vm.render(geo.size) {
                ZStack {
                    Color.blue
                    Text("Orientation: \(geo.size.width > geo.size.height ? "landscape" : "portrait")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```